# CloudFormation IAM Role -- AssumeRolePolicyDocument

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, amazon-policy

So I'm constructing a cf stack for a role in AWS and I don't know how to go about the `AssumeRolePolicyDocument` field when designing a role that is not resource-based.

All the examples I've tried to look up each have a specific AWS resource designated under the `"Principal"` field (e.g. `"Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"`).

What's the correct way to go about the `AssumeRolePolicyDocument` field for roles that are designed for users, not resources?

Comment: Could you provide more context on the problem you're trying to solve, for example, what sort of use-case are you designing the role for?

Comment: This is just for a dev role for a specific engineering division. You answered the question perfectly below! Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specify an AWS IAM user using the `AWS` key instead of `Service` as the `Principal` for a role policy document, including an AssumeRolePolicyDocument:

```
"Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AWS-account-ID:user/user-name" }
```

Refer to the [Specifying a Principal](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Principal_specifying) section of the IAM Policy Elements Reference for full details.